# filter pandas dataframe by time

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which I want to subset on time greater or less than 12pm. First i convert my string datetime to datetime[64]ns object in pandas.

```
segments_data['time'] = pd.to_datetime((segments_data['time']))
```

Then I separate time,date,month,year & dayofweek like below.

```
import datetime as dt

segments_data['date'] = segments_data.time.dt.date
segments_data['year'] = segments_data.time.dt.year
segments_data['month'] = segments_data.time.dt.month
segments_data['dayofweek'] = segments_data.time.dt.dayofweek
segments_data['time'] = segments_data.time.dt.time
```

My time column looks like following.

```
segments_data['time']
Out[1906]: 
  07:43:00
  07:52:00
  08:00:00
  08:42:00
  09:18:00
  09:18:00
  09:18:00
  09:23:00
  12:32:00
  12:43:00
  12:55:00
  Name: time, dtype: object
```

Now I want to subset dataframe with time greater than 12pm and time less than 12pm.

```
segments_data.time[segments_data['time'] < 12:00:00]
```

It doesn't work because `time` is a `string object`.

Answer (score 30):

**Update**

From pandas docs at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html. Thanks to Frederick in the comments.

Create dataframe with datetimes in it:

```
i = pd.date_range('2018-04-09', periods=4, freq='1D20min')
ts = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4]}, index=i)
ts
                     A
2018-04-09 00:00:00  1
2018-04-10 00:20:00  2
2018-04-11 00:40:00  3
2018-04-12 01:00:00  4
```

Use `between_time`:

```
ts.between_time('0:15', '0:45')
                     A
2018-04-10 00:20:00  2
2018-04-11 00:40:00  3
```

You get the times that are not between two times by setting start_time later than end_time:

```
ts.between_time('0:45', '0:15')
                     A
2018-04-09 00:00:00  1
2018-04-12 01:00:00  4
```

---

**Old Answer**

Leave a column as the raw datetime, call it `ts`:

```
segments_data['ts'] = pd.to_datetime((segments_data['time']))
```

Next you can cast the datetime to an `H:M:S` string and use `between(start,end)` seems to work:

```
In [227]:
segments_data=pd.DataFrame(x,columns=['ts'])
segments_data.ts = pd.to_datetime(segments_data.ts)
segments_data
Out[227]:
ts
0   2016-01-28 07:43:00
1   2016-01-28 07:52:00
2   2016-01-28 08:00:00
3   2016-01-28 08:42:00
4   2016-01-28 09:18:00
5   2016-01-28 09:18:00
6   2016-01-28 09:18:00
7   2016-01-28 09:23:00
8   2016-01-28 12:32:00
9   2016-01-28 12:43:00
10  2016-01-28 12:55:00

In [228]:    
 segments_data[segments_data.ts.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').between('00:00:00','12:00:00')]
Out[228]:
ts
0   2016-01-28 07:43:00
1   2016-01-28 07:52:00
2   2016-01-28 08:00:00
3   2016-01-28 08:42:00
4   2016-01-28 09:18:00
5   2016-01-28 09:18:00
6   2016-01-28 09:18:00
7   2016-01-28 09:23:00
```

Comment: It gives me an error `TypeError: can't compare datetime.time to str`

Comment: If you have a datetime column you can use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html

Comment: `between_time` requires datetime to be index. How do we apply it on one column? Am I missing something?

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. The columns that gets filtered needs to be a dt.time column, not a datetime. Try and apply this solution and it won't work

Answer (score 6):

Even though this post is 5 years old I just ran into this same problem and decided to post what I was able to get to work. I tried the between_time function but that did not work for me because the index on the dataframe had to be a datetime and I wanted to use one of the dataframe time columns to filter.

```
        # Import datetime libraries
    from datetime import datetime, date, time
        
    avail_df['Start'].dt.time
            1   08:36:44
            2   08:49:14
            3   09:26:00
            5   08:34:22
            7   08:34:19
            8   09:09:05
            9   12:27:43
           10   12:29:14
           12   09:05:55
           13   09:14:11
           14   09:21:41
           15   11:28:26
           16   12:25:10
           17   16:02:52
           18   08:53:51


# Use "time()" function to create start/end parameter I used 9:00am for this example 
avail_df.loc[avail_df['Start'].dt.time > time(9,00)]

3   09:26:00
8   09:09:05
9   12:27:43
10  12:29:14
12  09:05:55
13  09:14:11
14  09:21:41
15  11:28:26
16  12:25:10
17  16:02:52
20  09:04:50
21  09:21:35
22  09:22:05
23  09:47:05
24  09:55:05
```