# Pandas how to filter DataFrame on time period

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a file with the below table:

```
    Name        AvailableDate            totalRemaining
0   X3321       2018-03-14 13:00:00      200
1   X3321       2018-03-14 14:00:00      200
2   X3321       2018-03-14 15:00:00      200
3   X3321       2018-03-14 16:00:00      200
4   X3321       2018-03-14 17:00:00      193
```

I wanted to return a DataFrame with all the records in a specific **time** period regardless of the actual **date**.

I followed the example here:

[filter pandas dataframe by time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35052691/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-time)

but when I execute the below:

```
## setup
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

### Step 2
### Check available slots
file2 = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Files\data.xlsx'

slots = pd.read_excel(file2,na_values='')

## filter the preferred ones
slots['nextAvailableDate'] = pd.to_datetime((slots['nextAvailableDate']))


slots['times'] = pd.to_datetime((slots['nextAvailableDate']))
slots = slots[slots['times'].between('21:00:00', '02:00:00')]
```

This returns empty DataFrame as well as this solution:

```
slots = slots[slots['times'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S').between('21:00:00', '02:00:00')]
```

Is there a way to do it correctly without creating a columns for time separately? How I should approach this problem please?

My goal:

```
Name        AvailableDate            totalRemaining
0   X3321       2018-03-14 21:00:00      200
1   X3321       2018-03-14 22:00:00      200
2   X3321       2018-03-14 23:00:00      200
3   X3321       2018-03-14 00:00:00      200
4   X3321       2018-03-14 01:00:00      193
```

for every day that appears in the data set.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think need [`between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) working with `Datetimeindex` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), for columns add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for same order of columns:

```
print (slots)
     Name        AvailableDate  totalRemaining
0   X3321  2018-03-14 21:00:00             200
1   X3321  2018-03-14 20:00:00             200
2   X3321  2018-03-14 22:00:00             200
3   X3321  2018-03-14 23:00:00             200
4   X3321  2018-03-14 00:00:00             200
5   X3321  2018-03-14 01:00:00             193
6   X3321  2018-03-14 13:00:00             200
7   X3321  2018-03-14 14:00:00             200
8   X3321  2018-03-14 15:00:00             200
9   X3321  2018-03-14 16:00:00             200
10  X3321  2018-03-14 17:00:00             193

slots['AvailableDate'] = pd.to_datetime(slots['AvailableDate'])

df = (slots.set_index('AvailableDate')
          .between_time('21:00:00', '02:00:00')
          .reset_index()
          .reindex(columns=df.columns))
print (df)
        AvailableDate   Name  totalRemaining
0 2018-03-14 21:00:00  X3321             200
1 2018-03-14 22:00:00  X3321             200
2 2018-03-14 23:00:00  X3321             200
3 2018-03-14 00:00:00  X3321             200
4 2018-03-14 01:00:00  X3321             193
```

Comment: Works great Thank you. The NameError: name 'df' is not defined came up because I didn't pass correct DF to columns=df.columns. All good now.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `pd.Series.between` with `datetime` objects, as below.

```
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime.strptime('21:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
end = datetime.strptime('02:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()

slots = slots[slots['times'].dt.time.between(start, end)]
```

**Example usage**

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

slots = pd.DataFrame({'times': ['2018-03-08 05:00:00', '2018-03-08 07:00:00',
                                '2018-03-08 01:00:00', '2018-03-08 20:00:00',
                                '2018-03-08 22:00:00', '2018-03-08 23:00:00']})


slots['times'] = pd.to_datetime(slots['times'])

start = datetime.strptime('21:00:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
end = datetime.strptime('23:30:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()

slots = slots[slots['times'].dt.time.between(start, end)]

#                 times
# 4 2018-03-08 22:00:00
# 5 2018-03-08 23:00:00
```

Comment: it's a shame I can't reward both answers, your strptime was very useful later in the project I'm working on. Thank you