# Rows from pandas dataframe between two time values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe like this (with timestamp converted to datetime object):

```
    id  timestamp
0   221 2020-11-07 12:02:00
1   223 2020-11-08 13:21:00
2   224 2020-11-09 12:50:00
3   225 2020-11-10 14:23:00
4   226 2020-11-11 12:25:00
5   227 2020-11-14 14:26:00
```

I want to find number of rows between a time interval. e.g 12:00-13:00, here it would be 3 (entries 0, 2 and 4)

Comment: Looks like [between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) will be helpfull

Comment: Here's an example of between_time from SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35052691/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-time

Comment: Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select DataFrame rows between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370057/select-dataframe-rows-between-two-dates)

Comment: between_time would work. Just set timestamp as index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

Coerce timestamp to datetime and sort ascending

```
  df['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp']).sort_values(ascending=True)
```

Reset index but do not drop to keep id

```
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
```

Set timestamp as new index to allow use of df.betweeen time

```
df.set_index(df['timestamp'], inplace=True)
df.between_time('12:00', '13:00')
```

Answer (score 3):

So as I commented, I think you can just use [`between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) function:

```
CountRows = df.set_index('timestamp').between_time('12:00','13:00').shape[0]
```

This, in your case, sets column `timestamp` as index and then returns the count of rows between the two timevalues. Where:

> *"The first element of the tuple returned by `Dataframe.shape` contains
>   the number of items in index in a dataframe i.e. basically the number
>   of rows in the dataframe.* [Source](https://thispointer.com/pandas-count-rows-in-a-dataframe-all-or-those-only-that-satisfy-a-condition/)

Comment: and if you need the results, just remove `.shape[0]`

Answer (score 1):

Since I believe that suggested [between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) works only for `DatetimeIndex`, you can either set your `DataFrame index` to `'timestamp'` and then use `between_time` or, alternatively, first, use [sorting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

```
df.sort_values(by='timestamp',axis='columns',inplace=True)
```

Then use [sorted search](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html)

```
start = df['timestamp'].searchsorted(pd.Timestamp('2020-11-07 12:00:00'), side='left')
end = df['timestamp'].searchsorted(pd.Timestamp('2020-11-07 13:00:00'), side='right')
```

Then find number of rows

```
count = start - end
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by posts in Comments section [between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) works well. One need to make timestamp (which is a datetime64 object here) a index first, then use the between_time function.