# How to remove rows where a datetime column matches interval condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I’m downloading market intraday data points with extended hours (from 4am until 8pm EST). I need to get rid of those extended hours on each day, keeping only entries between 9:30am and 4pm.

A data sample:

```
time,...
2018-11-13 04:05,...
2018-11-13 07:05,...
2018-11-13 08:05,...
2018-11-13 09:00,...
2018-11-13 10:00,...
...
2018-11-13 15:00,...
2018-11-13 16:00,...
2018-11-13 17:00,...
2018-11-13 18:00,...
2018-11-13 19:00,...
2018-11-13 20:00,...
```

So, for the ‘time’ column, I need to keep only entries greater than 9:30 and less than 16:00 (on each day).

How can I filter that out?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filter pandas dataframe by time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35052691/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.between_time`. If your dataframe looks like:

```
                time col
0   2018-11-13 04:05   a
1   2018-11-13 07:05   b
2   2018-11-13 08:05   c
3   2018-11-13 09:00   d
4   2018-11-13 10:00   e
5   2018-11-13 15:00   f
6   2018-11-13 16:00   g
7   2018-11-13 17:00   h
8   2018-11-13 18:00   i
9   2018-11-13 19:00   j
10  2018-11-13 20:00   k
```

Then:

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df = df.set_index('time')
print( df.between_time('09:30', '16:00') )
```

Prints:

```
                    col
time                   
2018-11-13 10:00:00   e
2018-11-13 15:00:00   f
2018-11-13 16:00:00   g
```

Comment: Exact. Check doc here : [between time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html?highlight=time#pandas.DataFrame.between_time)

Comment: Maybe `df.groupby(df.index.date).apply(lambda x: x.between_time('09:30','16:00'))` Just in case he needs to find the time range in multiple days?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question has been already given by another user [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35052691/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-time).

You have to use `df.between_time(from, to)`. Here is a code example:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(path_to_your_file) # or use another way to read / create dataframe
df.between_time('9:30', '16:00')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the time from dates then just check the time and query those with true

```
format = "%H:%M"
df = df.loc[df['time'].dt.time>day.strftime("9:30", format) and df['time'].dt.time<day.strftime("16:00", format)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
df.loc['2018-11-13 09:30':'2018-11-13 16:00']
```