# Pandas filter dataframe by time

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time

This is not a duplicate of: [filter pandas dataframe by time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35052691/filter-pandas-dataframe-by-time) because the solution offered there doesn't address the same column type that needs to be filtered.

I have the following dataframe:

```
i = pd.date_range('2018-04-09', periods=4, freq='1D20min')
ts = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
               'B':i})
ts['date'] = pd.to_datetime(ts['B']).dt.date
ts['time'] = pd.to_datetime(ts['B']).dt.time
ts = ts.drop('B', axis = 1)
```

I want to filter on just the `time` columns and i tried this:

```
ts['time'].between_time('0:45', '0:15')
```

But it doesn't work. I get the error: `TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex`

Do you have any idea how to do this? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Solution without `B` column:

If need filter by `time` column use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
from datetime import  time

df = ts[ts['time'].between(time(0,15,0), time(0,45,0))]
print (df)
   A                   B        date      time
1  2 2018-04-10 00:20:00  2018-04-10  00:20:00
2  3 2018-04-11 00:40:00  2018-04-11  00:40:00
```

Original solution with `B` column:

Create `DatetimeIndex` if need filter by [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html):

```
df = ts.set_index('B').between_time('0:15', '0:45')
print (df)
                     A        date      time
B                                           
2018-04-10 00:20:00  2  2018-04-10  00:20:00
2018-04-11 00:40:00  3  2018-04-11  00:40:00
```

Solution again with `DatetimeIndex` with [`DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.indexer_between_time.html) for positions of matched rows and selecting by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = ts.iloc[ts.set_index('B').index.indexer_between_time('0:15', '0:45')]
print (df)
   A                   B        date      time
1  2 2018-04-10 00:20:00  2018-04-10  00:20:00
2  3 2018-04-11 00:40:00  2018-04-11  00:40:00
```

Comment: Thanks! The second option works for me. The first one doesn't but that's my fault, because actually I posed my question slightly wrong because in reality `B` is no longer part of the data frame, I updated my Q, this time dropping column `B`.

Comment: Also, what if you want to get the times outside of the time periods specified?

Comment: @stevezissou - If need outside use `df = ts[~ts['time'].between(time(0,15,0), time(0,45,0))]`

Comment: it's my fault as I initally included `B`, but to make this question stand out from the other linked in the OP, you could delete the first part of the answer.

Comment: @stevezissou - I change ordering, I prefer not remove, because in future some another developer should use it. Is it acceptable for you?

Comment: Great, thanks, I accepted. I would prefer to remove the `B` column answer, even though that was the original, because a similar solution is linked in a different post. But if you prefer it this way then I'll roll with it. Thanks again.

Comment: @stevezissou - In my opinion this is perfectly fine, happy coding!